# Individual onclick for every button of the same class in Android

Tags: android, class, onclick

the Problem is the following... I made a class with a button and some stuff around it. Now I can add this button to the screen by creating an object. Example:

```
FloatingButton button = new FloatingButton();
```

I did this 3 times in my main activity. Therefore, I have 3 Buttons now. The Problem is that I want to add a different onclick event to each of the Buttons. So if I add an onclick event in the FloatingButton class every Button would do the same. So I need to set the onclick event from the main activity. Is that possible?

Comment: Their is a interface named  View.OnClickListener, which is used for implementation of click feature in the whole page, inside this click feature you can get any buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setOnClickListener` allows your to add a click listener directly to the button wherever you have access to it. So in your case you could add a listener after you instantiate each button in the activity.

Example:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using just one click listener and you can check for the id of the view.

```
  final OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
      case R.id.button_1:
        doButtonOne()
        break;
      case R.id.button_2:
        doButtonTwo()
        break;
        ...
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you created the buttons did you name them differently?

```
FloatingButton buttonYes = new FloatingButton();
FloatingButton buttonNo = new FloatingButton();
```

And then use setOnClickListener for each of the buttons you created with the code you want executed on a button press.

```
buttonYes.setOnClickListener(...)
buttonNo.setOnClickListener(...)
```

This will enable you to have presses on different buttons produce different results.